# Constructing a tree from an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am a beginner, prompt algorithm for constructing a tree from an array of the form:

```
var data = [
   {id: 1,level:1,left_key:1,right_key:12, caption: "Books"},
   {id: 2,level:2,left_key:2,right_key:11, caption: "Programming"},
   {id: 3,level:3,left_key:3,right_key:4, caption: "Languages"},
   {id: 4,level:3,left_key:5,right_key:10, caption: "Databases"},
   {id: 5,level:4,left_key:6,right_key:7, caption: "MongoDB"},
   {id: 6,level:4,left_key:8,right_key:9, caption: "dbm"}
];
```

The data format is taken from here [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-nested-sets/). 
From the data in this format on request from the Mongodb database to be built tree species:

```
<ol>      
   <li>
       <span> Books </span>
       <ol>
           <li>
              <span> Programming </span>
           </li>
       </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```

I can not understand the principle of tree traversal.
P.S. I'd like to do without the third-party libraries

Comment: Are you working from an example or are you looking for a good way to do this? Hint, you are using MongoDB so just store the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this

```
function make_tree() {    
  var tree = document.getElementById("tree");
  data.forEach(function(elem){
    var elem_parent = document.getElementById("tree_" + elem.level);    
    if(elem_parent){      
      var cur_element = document.createElement("li");
      cur_element.setAttribute('id','tree_' + elem.level + "_" + elem.id);
      cur_element.innerHTML = "<span>" + elem.caption + "</span>";
      elem_parent.appendChild(cur_element);
    }
    else {      
      var cur_parent = document.createElement("ol");
      cur_parent.setAttribute('id','tree_' + elem.level);      
      var cur_element = document.createElement("li");
      cur_element.setAttribute('id','tree_' + elem.level + "_" + elem.id);
      cur_element.innerHTML = "<span>" + elem.caption + "</span>";
      cur_parent.appendChild(cur_element);
      parent_before = document.getElementById("tree_" + (elem.level - 1)); 
      if (parent_before) parent_before.appendChild(cur_parent);
      else tree.appendChild(cur_parent);
    }
  });
}
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z23rR/)**

Answer (score 0):

The better answer to this is to simply store the tree structure within your MongoDB document:

```js
{
    "0": {
        "caption": "Books",
        "items": {
            "0": {
                "caption": "Programming",
                "items": {
                    "0": {
                        "caption": "Languages",
                    },
                    "1": {
                        "caption": "Databases",
                        "items": {
                            "0": {
                                "caption": "MongoDB"
                             },
                             "1": {
                                 "caption": "dbm"
                             }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That has a natural order to it and provides in a single read a very easy way to get a structure that can be traversed in the concept of building a menu.

It is also very simple to update, so to add a new item to, say the "Languages" level, then you have a clear path to update:

```
 db.collection.update(
     {},
     {
       "$set": { 
           "0.items.0.items.0.items.0.caption": "C++"
       }
     }
)
```

And to add another:

```
 db.collection.update(
     {},
     {
       "$set": { 
           "0.items.0.items.0.items.1.caption": "Pascal"
       }
     }
)
```

Now this as with all tree structures does require some knowledge of the level you are inserting at. The design here ( and horribly over-engineered ) is at least allowing easy updates. It is a structure that would be notoriously bad to query but that is not the point.

But of course the limitation here is for "small" tree structures (which is still under 16MB and a quite a lot of tree), but for anything that was particularly large that is where larger model implementations come in

The thing with processing trees in the way as presented in the sample data is that each node needs to be pulled in one at at time. So exactly as stated in the documentation you are pulling results like this:

```
var databaseCategory = db.categories.findOne( { _id: "Databases" } );
db.categories.find({ 
    left: { $gt: databaseCategory.left }, 
    right: { $lt: databaseCategory.right } 
});
```

So there is a a way of pulling all the children out from a given node, but now consider what you need to do in order to add any new items:

So in order to add something in the languages node as was done earlier, not only are you dealing with inserting a new value, but also updating all the other node values in the tree to represent there position as shown in the example documentation.

There are ways around that by "bucketing" the values on nodes in order to allow for insertion and removal, but much as the whole subject of modelling tree structures like this, is way out of scope for an answer on this site.

So for your given use case of producing a menu, you are better off using the native data structure features of your storage and simply storing and calling the data with a native structure to how you are going to use it.

Comment: Initially, the kind of data was exactly as you wrote, but there were problems with the CRUD operations. Too complex queries for data retrieval deeply nested data. I do not know what to do, I just need to present data from mongodb in a tree on the HTML page. Can I choose too complicated way?

Comment: @timkit an alternative approach is to use arrays, at least at some depth. Updating and inserting are fairly easy with a structure like what is shown. Nested arrays have problems due to only being able to match the first found position in the first array. I depends on your actual use case, which you have not presented here. As it stands this question only serves to point out the complications with a relatively open model, and suggest that you should be using a more native structure for small data. The referenced example is actually more of a computer science solution.

Comment: To clarify what I want to get: [link jsfiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/timkit/64gR5/)

Comment: @timkit That is understood but you probably actually want to process a structure that is "native" into your menu. That is what the response is about. If you have another question about actually processing your response data in either a template or as a JSON response then you can ask **another** question which myself or others will happily answer. But your **specific** question on how to manage a **tree** for your menu structure, I believe to be answered.